# Extract a value on the line below the current $sql line extracted

Tags: php, sql

I have a table `mytable` with these columns `string` `pagename`

I have to extract the $pagename but I also need to extract the next $pagename on the line below this one for page navigation. For example if I need the `$pagename` value `WHERE string='100001'` I will need the next page name that would be where `$string` is equal to `$nextpagestr=($currentline['string']+1);` or `100002` (knowing my closing brace for $sql is after $sql2)

I've tried the code below but when I hover the link it shows `Array.php` instead of the value I was expecting

```
    <?php
    include 'includes/connectdb.php';

    $sql="select * from mytable where string=100001";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($currentline=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        extract($currentline);

    $nextpagestr=($currentline['string']+1);
    $previouspagestr=($currentline['string']-1);

    ?>

     <!-- SOME CODE HERE ... -->  <?php echo $currentline['pagename']; ?>

     <!-- THEN MY NAVIGATION: -->  
     <a class="next-link" href="<?php 
     $sql2='SELECT pagename FROM mytable WHERE string=$nextpagestr'; 
     $result2 = mysql_query($sql2); 
     while($pagename=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
     {echo($pagename);} ?>.php">Next Page</a>


    <?php } ?>  <!-- CLOSING BRACE FOR THE FIRST $SQL -->
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm....

```
 $result2 = mysql_query($sql2); 
 while($currentline=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
 {
     extract($currentline);
     echo($currentline['pagename']); ?>.php">Next Page</a>
 <?php } ?>
```